# How to choose last element and verify his attribute

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autotest

I wrote a test where the user sends a message to another. I need to choose every time last message that was sent and verify his attribute value.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chatView\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]")).sendKeys("Hello SMS");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chatView\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.id("messagesContainer"));

    WebElement lastElement = getLast.driver.findElement(By.className("message-item"));

    System.out.println(lastElement);

    System.out.println(lastElement.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus"));
```

Answer (score 3):

`findElements(By.id("messagesContainer"))` will return you list of one element, the parent element of the messages. If you want the messages you need to use

```
List<WebElement> messages = driver.findElements(By.className("message-item"));
```

To get the last one use the index of list size minus 1

```
List<WebElement> messages = driver.findElements(By.className("message-item"));
WebElement lastMessage = messages.get(messages.size() - 1);
Assert.assertEquals(lastMessage.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus"), "sent");
```

Comment: Thank you, but i get error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: @VladyslavNikonov are you sure `message-item` is the correct class name? matbe you can add the html.

Comment: i got div id="messagesContainer"

Comment: and div class="message-item" for each message

Comment: @VladyslavNikonov Are the messages inside `frame`/`iframe` by any chance?

Comment: List<WebElement> messages = driver.findElements(By.id("messagesContainer"));
        WebElement lastMessage = messages.get(messages.size() - 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(lastMessage.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus"), "failed");

Comment: its the last error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [failed] but found [null]

Comment: @VladyslavNikonov Don't look for `By.id("messagesContainer")`, its the messages container, not the messages themselves. Use `List<WebElement> messages = driver.findElements(By.className("message-item"));`

Comment: You can also try `List<WebElement> messages = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#messagesContainer > div"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the size of the list minus one.

```
List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.id("messagesContainer"));

WebElement lastElement = webElements.get(webElements.size() - 1)); 

// example test in testng, expecting SENT
Assert.assertEquals(lastElement.getAttribute("data-deliverystatus"), "SENT");
```